# How to create a data object from the list of displayed element in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html is like below:

```
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jquery, I want to create an object like following from the above HTML:

```
[
  {
    position :1,
    url: "https://link_to_Item_1"
  },
  {
    position :"2",
    url: "https://link_to_Item_1"
  },
  {
    position :"3",
    url: "https://link_to_Item_2"
  }
]
```

I tried something like below:

```
var myData = [];
var myDataElements = {};
$('.list-item').find('a').each(function(index, ele){
    myDataElements.position = index;
    myDataElements.url = $(this).attr('href');
myData.push(myDataElements);    
});
```

But the result was the position and URL became the same for all elements in myData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable `myDataElements` inside the loop :

```
var myDataElements = {};
```

And make sure you're closing the anchor tag well like :

```
<a href="https://link_to_Item_1"></a>
```

Instead of :

```
<a href="https://link_to_Item_1" />
```

**NOTE:** You can increase the index by 1 if you want to start counting from 1 instead of zero since the index is zero-based.

```js
var myData = [];

$('.list-item a').each(function(index, ele) {
  var myDataElements = {};

  myDataElements.position = index + 1;
  myDataElements.url = $(this).attr('href');

  myData.push(myDataElements);
});

console.log(myData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_1"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_2"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_3"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IMO, this is a good answer as it explained source of the issue and had shown how to fix it. +1

Answer (score 5):

The  issue is you are declaring the object outside. But you need the object in each iteration, declare that inside the function:

```js
var myData = [];
$('.list-item').find('a').each(function(index, ele){
  var myDataElements = {};
  myDataElements.position = index + 1;
  myDataElements.url = $(this).attr('href');
  myData.push(myDataElements);    
});
console.log(myData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) like the following way:

```js
var myData = $('.details').map(function(i, el){
  return {
    position: i+1,
    url: $(el).find('a').attr('href')
  }
}).get();
console.log(myData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <div class="details">
    <a href="https://link_to_Item_3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your second edit is basically explained by others already. Your first edit attempts to show how to write idiomatic code to solve the problem, instead of explaining what was wrong in the OPs code and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`myDataElements` here pointing to the same object. And with each iteration you are basically changing the value of its 2 properties, `position` and `url` and then pushing it to the array. All array elements of `myData` are same object which you created here `var myDataElements = {};`. That's is why you ended up with same objects in `myData`.

What you want here is:

```
myData.push(Object.assign({}, myDataElements);
// or  myData.push({...myDataElements});
```

Now you are **creating a new object** by copying the `myDataElements` before pushing it it the array `myData`. This gives you the desired output.